# Why is Web Request content truncated

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a Web Service which is doing some screen scraping of an aspx website.

I can get it to log in successfully, but then when I submit a request, it returns a server error.  When I check it out with Fiddler, it shows that the content (the query string) is being truncated so it is not all submitted.  The content is quite long over 3600 chars. (Not my choice, it's just the way the website was created and what it expects.)

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(REQUESTUSAGE) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.CookieContainer = this.Cookies;
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
requestWriter.Write(GetPostDataForRequest());

WebResponse response = null;

try
{
    response = webRequest.GetResponse();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{}
```

The GetPostDataForRequest returns the content, but like I said, Fiddler shows it is missing the last 600 chars or so for no apparent reason.  The debugger shows the string is returned as expected, but somehow it does not get written correctly.

So how to I get it to submit the full string?

Comment: You say that the query string is 3600 chars ?

Comment: What's wrong with `WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();`? Why ignore any exceptions?

Comment: Your correct.  In this case, it was still under testing, so I hadn't added exception handling.

Comment: I run into the same problem today

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got this resolved.  I was not closing the requestWriter.

Comment: Yes, your `StreamWriter` should be in a `using` block. Maybe the `WebResponse` as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are usually limits to the request size - take a look at [maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

It appears that you are running into a browser issue, not a server issue.  Can you issue the request with a command line tool (i.e. something like wget) to verify that it is not a problem with the server?

You can also try a different browser, which may have different limits.